# Telethon How to receive a video message from one group and then send the video to another group

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

Telethon is a way to send videos from other channels to your own group. Currently, I have tried this method, but there is a problem with this method. If there are N videos in a message, the message will be split into multiple videos and sent, such as one video and one message.  I was hoping to merge the videos and send them

```
    @bot.on(events.NewMesage(func=lambda e: e.media))
async def test(event): 
    await event.client.send_message("me",event.text or "caption", file=event.media)
```